# How to export Chinese characters encoded UTF-8 from MySql to SQL correctly

Tags: php, mysql, database, encoding, utf-8

We are fighting with serious problem last three day,

We exported our MySql database file from PhpmyAdmin, Data was written inside database entries is Chinese with UTF-8 Char-Set, After exporting its converted to Latin Char-Set,

Now we are importing this Database SQl file to other host, We importing this data on on UTF-8 and Collation UTF-general-ci, But data is still in Latin Char i cant see Chinese, Moreover we tried almost all Charset in importing this SQL file, but still now result,

Please someone can help for this.

Regards

Comment: does  the problem happen when you select mysql record with php ?

Comment: no, Infact, after uploading This we are doing Post in CMS, data is storing is correct Chinese char, its not importing previous Existing data from SQL Script, you can see our web www.luxos.cn, you will see first post we mase is working fine, the problem is only when we are restoring our DB script, latin char are apearing not Chinese,

Comment: have you tried to insert  `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");` into your mysql connection config file after your mysql connection details ?

Comment: besides the suggestion by @ValehHajiyev , try these all as well:
        `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`
 `mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");`
 `mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_general_ci'");`

Comment: it sounds like you are misconfigurating the export from phpmyadmin, i would do the export from command line `mysqldump -h{host} -u{user} -p {dbname}>{dbname}.sql`