# Chinese in the database

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guru of programming! Today I have got the task from my manager to add `Chinese` locale to my site.

Please if you can, what kind of encoding should I use in `MySQL` database, and will I have any problems with displaying Chinese text on client side?

Thank you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620179/how-to-export-chinese-characters-encoded-utf-8-from-mysql-to-sql-correctly) for a solution to database handeling. You will also need to set the php to header the same charset I would have thought

Particularly at the suggestion by [nazar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/823795/nazar) at [this thread...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620179/how-to-export-chinese-characters-encoded-utf-8-from-mysql-to-sql-correctly#comment12215298_9620179)